# Относительные ссылки в файле стилей (WordPress)

Tags: html, css, wordpress, http, https

Есть сайт, который работает на протоколе `https`, но некоторые картинки, или другие файлы например этот:

```
  url('../fonts/arqicon.ttf?-acjeuq')
```

который прописан в файле CSS, подтягивается с протоколом `http`, из за чего не работает `https`.

Кто знает, почему в файле стилей генерируется ссылка с протоколом `http`, а не `https`?

---

проблема была в том что плохо настроен сервер, из за чего и происходила эта ситуация.

Comment: Почему css подтягивается по http? От чего вообще это файл стилей? (а вообще так не правильно включать шрифты)

Comment: У вас, значит, сам css-файл загружается по http.

Answer (score 0):

На WP существуют плагины, которые перекидывают все исходящие подключения на http.
Лично я просто скачал все содержимое, вместе с CMS, и в notepad++ сделал замену http на https во всех файлах. 
Помогло, хром начал отмечать сайт как безопасный.